# How to repair Windows 7 boot loader on UEFI system?

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, uefi, vhd, bcdboot

On a Windows 7 Home Premium PC, I tried creating a Windows 8 VHD and booting to it.  I created a VHD as my E: drive, installed Win8 into it with `imagex`, and then ran `bcdboot E:\Windows`.  I've done this countless times before on various laptops, but I just encountered a system where it didn't work.  It's an Asus Republic of Gamers G75V.

When I boot, it now says:

`Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key.`

I do not have a proper Windows 7 recover DVD, but I do have an ISO of Windows 7 Home Premium x64 with SP1.  When I boot to a USB thumb drive running that, Windows says it cannot repair this version of Windows.

I booted a Windows 8 Enterprise Edition 90 day trial ISO, said "Repair", and found a command prompt.  I see the Windows 7 disk as C:.  I tried `bcdboot C:\Windows`, but that failed.  I then tried `bcdboot C:\Windows /s C:`, and it succeeded, but when rebooting I get the same error as above.

What should I do?  Also, does my UEFI boot setting matter?